# Strange Thread.sleep behaviour

Tags: android

So i want to wait 60 seconds before uploading a file to the server and here's my "wait" code:

```
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "waiting 1 minute before upload");
            for ( int i = 0; i < 60; i ++ ) {
                Debug.log(( 60 - i ) + " seconds left...");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and i get the log till 13 seconds are left. Its always stuck at "13 seconds left..." even after waiting for 1+ hour! Any help with this please?

btw Debug.Log is the same as Log.i xcept that it adds the strign in a array list as well.

Comment: are you doing this in separate thread asynchronously?

Comment: Yes. this is in the void run() method.

Comment: Perhaps the device is falling asleep.

Comment: The activity is still active. I press random buttons just to keep the phone screen on...

Comment: and, shoudlt it continue later even if it fell asleep?

Comment: Attach a debugger and see what it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `TimerTask` class istead.

it has a `wait(long miliseconds)` method and implements  `Runnable`  that you can use it like 
thread.

or using `Timer` class may help you too.

Here is the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html)

Comment: Tried it any works now. Though its still a mistery to me why it stopped just like that. Well TimerTask works! Thanks.